# MutableLiveData doesn't work, ObservableField does - why?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, mutablelivedata

I have a very simple code in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text="@={viewModel.password}"
    android:enabled="@{viewModel.inputEnabled}">
```

Now when `viewModel.inputEnabled` is a `MutableLiveData<Boolean>` underneath, it simply doesn't work, edit is always enabled, regardless of value of `inputEnabled`. However, it takes only to change `inputEnabled` to an `ObservableField<Boolean>` (and switch `setValue` to `set`) such that it immediately starts working.

Why is that so? How can I make `MutableLiveData` work correctly?

Note, that this field is used in three places (to enable/disable form during processing).

Answer (score 4):

I ran in to same issue....make sure to call following in your activity/fragment:

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```